# React native: Give stack nav header access to a screen's state and another screen's function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Using stack navigator I have:

- A custom header component **SaveButton.js**.
- A form component **AddItem.js**.
- A screen component that renders the data **Food.js**

**Router.js**

```
export const FoodStack = StackNavigator({
  Food: {
    screen: Food,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Food',
      headerRight: <AddButton navigation={navigation} />, //navigates to AddItem
    })
  },
  AddItem: {
    screen: AddItem,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Add Food',
      headerRight: <SaveButton navigation={navigation} />,
    })
  },
});
```

I need SaveButton.js to have access to AddItem.js state (contains user input) and a function in Food.js (retrieves data). That way, when save is clicked, I can grab state & store it and re-render data using the function.

**SaveButton.js**

```
export default class SaveButton extends Component {

onPress = async () => {
  const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
  const { myData } = //Get myData from AddItem.js state
  const data = { myData };
  await store.push('array', data);
//Invoke getData in Food.js
  goBack();
};

render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.onPress}
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Save</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've tried similar answers that involve passing data through `navigation.state.params` but I can't work out how to adapt for this instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for props change in your component and set a specific parameter on header button press.

**Example**

```
export const FoodStack = StackNavigator({
  Food: {
    screen: Food,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Food',
      headerRight: <AddButton navigation={navigation} />, //navigates to AddItem
    })
  },
  AddItem: {
    screen: AddItem,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Add Food',
      headerRight: <SaveButton navigation={navigation} onPress={() => navigaion.setParams({saveItem: true}) />,
    })
  },
});
```

---

```
export default class SaveButton extends Component {

onPress = () => {
  if(this.props.onPress) this.props.onPress();
};

render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.onPress}
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Save</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
}
```

---

```
export default class AddItem extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { params: prevParams } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const { params: nextParams } = nextProps.navigation.state;

    if(prevParams.saveItem !== nextParams.saveItem && nextParams.saveItem === true) {
      // I used a simple boolean value, you can pass an object with data to save
      this.saveItem();
    }
  }
  saveItem = () => {
    //run you save function here
    //then set parameter back to false
    this.props.navigation.setParams({saveItem: false});
    // then you can go back
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  }
  render() {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you mind explain the code inside the `componentWillReceiveProps` method? I'm not sure how to alter this to receive my data held in state

Comment: @garethiv in componentWillReceiveProps I deconstruct the state from the current props and next props and compare them. You can implement your version of it. Mine was just an example.

Comment: I can't seem to get compWillReceiveProps to fire, even if I take out the comparison of current to previous props. Therefore, when I hit the save button, my saveItem method is not being called